# How would I update a cloud database structure with minimal impact on Mobile Apps

Tags: cloud, azure-mobile-services, mobile-application

I am new to mobile app development and I was curious what some common approaches are to updating the structure of a cloud service. Lets say I currently have a mobile service in Azure and v1.0 mobile app has been up and running for a while. Now it is time for v2.0 which has new tables, maybe restructures the data around. How do you push this change out without breaking all the v1.0 apps. I have a couple ideas, but I just kinda came up with these on my own, there is probably a better way?...

1) In the app, check for when the update to cloud storage has been pushed, and when it has...tell the user to update to the new version? I don't necessarily like this approach because it would stop the user from using the app entirely until the upgrade.

2) Have a v2.0 cloud instance that has all the changes and point the new version of the app to this new cloud service and migrate the data over (somehow...unknown really)...when the user has upgrade to 2.0...haven't fully thought this one out yet tho.

Any direction would be great! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to migrate the v1 data to v2 instance of database using the SQL Management studio. Then you would have to release the new version of your app to market and user will be notified to upgrade the app whenever they open it next on their devices.